# ng-grid row template mouse events don't work for an editable row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm creating a ng-grid with a editable column like this:

```
{field:'quantity', displayName:'Quantity', enableCellEdit:true, cellTemplate:'myCellTemplate.html'}
```

myCellTemplate.html:

```
<div ng-click="alert('foo')" ng-mouseover="hovered=true" ng-class="{myHoverClass:hovered}">
     <span>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span>
</div>
```

The ng-click doesn't work (i.e. no popup), also the ng-mouseover doesn't work either. How do I get this template to react to mouse events?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update the plunker for this? Ideally whatever you are using should work

Comment: That comment puzzles me more than the question.